# When using LoadSceneMode.Additive, the next scene with ARkit is not working properly?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

When I click ViewAR it Loads the next scene 
      `SceneManager.LoadScene("scene2", LoadSceneMode.Additive);`
In the second scene I am using ARkit to detect a plane and using UnityARHitTestExample I am placing an object on the detected plane.I cannot place the model it is stuck in the centre but if I use `Loadscene.Single` for the above code it works smoothly.

The reason I am using `LoadSceneMode.Additive` is that when I hit back button from the scene 2 it should go exactly where I left in scene 1.That is if my scene 1 contains two pages,at start if I hit next it reaches second page.In the second page I have ViewAR button which when clicked goes to scene 2.From scene 2 when I hit back button it should return to page 2 in scene 1.

If I use `LoadSceneMode.Additive`I cannot place the model using HittestExample.That is when a plane is detected I cannot place the gameobject on a detected plane.It is stuck at centre.

```
 public void ViewAR()
    {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Option", Buttonoption);
    ProductDetails.SetActive(false);
    ViewARbtn.SetActive(false);

    StartCoroutine(Changescene());


    StartCoroutine(LoadScene2());
   // SceneManager.LoadScene("furnitres", LoadSceneMode.Additive);


}

IEnumerator Changescene()
{

    SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync("Home");
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

}

IEnumerator LoadScene2()
{
    AsyncOperation asyncLoad =SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync("furnitres", LoadSceneMode.Additive); 


    // Wait until the asynchronous scene fully loads
    while (!asyncLoad.isDone)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

}
```

The problem here is two scenes are interfering when I use Additive is what I think.I do not want to reload the first scene at the same time I cannot use `LoadSceneMode.Additive` .Any solution on how to get back to scene 1 when I hit back button in scene 2?I tried loading the scene 2 asynchronously.